# How do you perform Sajda Tilawat? (Prostration of Recitation)

Tags: quran-recitation, sajda, sajdat-al-tilaawah

What is the proper procedure for performing Sajda Tilawah?

Comment: **Related: [Sajda of Tilawah in Quran](http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/2267/59).**

Comment: **Related: [Is the sajdah tilawah (prostration of recitation) obligatory or recommended?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/1431/59).**

Answer (score 3):

You do a Takbeer and then go down into sajdah, and then you get up without saying a takbeer and there is no Tasleem, unless you are in salat when you would say a takbeer when you go down into it and come up.

When in the Sujood, you can say:

> سبحان ربي الأعلى
>
> Glory be to my Lord Most High, glory be to my Lord Most High

Also, the Dua' you say in the Sujood is:

> سَجَدَ وَجْهِي لِلَّذِي خَلَقَهُ وَشَقَّ سَمْعَهُ وَبَصَرَهُ
> بِحَوْلِهِ وَقُوَّتِهِ
>
> My face prostrates itself to Him Who created it and brought forth its
> hearing and seeing by His might and power
>
> [Sunan Abi Dawood](http://sunnah.com/abudawud/7/14)

As well as:

> اللَّهُمَّ اكْتُبْ لِي بِهَا عِنْدَكَ أَجْرًا وَضَعْ عَنِّي بِهَا
> وِزْرًا وَاجْعَلْهَا لِي عِنْدَكَ ذُخْرًا وَتَقَبَّلْهَا مِنِّي كَمَا
> تَقَبَّلْتَهَا مِنْ عَبْدِكَ دَاوُدَ
>
> O Allah! Record for me, a reward with You for it, remove a sin for me
> by it, and store it away for me with You, and accept it from me as You
> accepted it from Your worshiper Dawood
>
> [Jami'i Attirmidhi](http://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/6/36)

Comment: im shia and we say in sajda :
سُبْحانَ رَبِّی الاعْلى وَ بِحَمْدِهِ or 3 times : سُبْحَانَ اللَّهِ